# Firebase Database is not in pod folder after install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

In my pod file I have added various pods of which all work except firebase database.

I can use the finder to open the pod folder in my project and it shows all pods with its assets aswell as the firebase database. However when i load up xcode, checking under the pod folder the firebase database folder vanishes which i assume is why i cant import the module. But why is this happening.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaOZp.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJw2P.png)

Comment: can you share your pod file here.

Answer (score 0):

**You should add this line to your podfile, if not exists**

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

And in your terminal -> Path to your project.

```
pod install
```

Hope it will helps

Comment: Thanks but this has already been done hence why it is in the pod folder in finder. Just confused as to how it isnt showing in xcode though.